# Exported .obj has some transparent parts

Tags: objects, three.js

I exported a tshirt model in .obj format with its uv map. When i load the model with threejs, the tshirt interior is transparent.

I tried all the methods i found in other posts like recalculate normals or change uv seems but the result is always the same.

How can i make visible these parts? Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: Tshirt with transparent interior]

[image: Tshirt with transparent interior bottom]

Comment: If mesh doesn't have any thickness (e.g you didn't use Solidify modifier or alike), then when viewed at the inside part of the shirt holes would be visible because from that point of view all faces' normals are oriented wrong side. If you want mesh to be solid from any point of view add thickness to it, Solidify modifier, Solidify command in Edit mode etc.

Comment: Have you tried setting `mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material